# Drawing a chunk with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, vbo

I have some trouble with my shader/vbo/vao stuffs with OpenGL.

### Situation

I have created a **geometry shader** that allows me to draw a cube from a position (Position set using uniforms).

I'm trying to use a **chunk system** to **reduce my draw calls**. The problem is that I can't find a way to start. How to reduce draw calls but still render as many cubes ?

### Implementation ideas

I was thinking about re-working my geometry shader with 3 for-loops of 16 iterations to generates vertex positions of my 4096 cubes. The other possibility I had in mind was to call 4096 times my shader for each position. (I'm a beginner in OpenGL but I'm not sure that is possible).

### My difficulties

- Should I send those positions (Or indexes in my chunk that I'll convert to position) to my shader with uniform or a VBO ?
- In the case of a VBO, is it possible to send an array of `uint8_t` ? Each element of the array will contain a byte to tell the block type, 0 for air, 1 for dirt. Note that the array indexes will get used to determine block position. (*Exemple: `chunk_data[0][5][2]` position will be `vec3(0.f, 5.f, 2.f) + chunk_position` and his type is dirt*).
- Again in the case I choose to go for a VBO, is it possible to change : `layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;` to an array of bytes (int I guess because GLSL doesn't provide bytes/uint8_t)

### Edit

I found, thanks to @Acorn that instanced drawing could help me to improve my performances. I'm now trying to understand how instanced drawing really works and how to apply this to my problem. For now I think that I need to define what will contain my instanced array (I guess it will be blocks positions and types)

### Resources

**RenderingManager.cpp (Method that handle voxel drawing)**

```
void ElkRendering::Managers::RenderingManager::DrawVoxel(const glm::vec3 & p_position)
{
    if (m_currentTexture && m_currentShader)
    {
        m_currentShader->SetUniformVec3("u_position", p_position);
        m_voxel.Draw(*m_currentShader);
    }
}
```

**Voxel.cpp (Setup and draw methods)**

```
void Voxel::Setup()
{
    GLfloat verts[] =
    {
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
    };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vao);
    glGenBuffers(1, &m_vbo);

    glBindVertexArray(m_vao);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void Voxel::Draw(Shader& p_shader)
{
    PROFILER_SPY("Voxel::Draw");

    glBindVertexArray(m_vao);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

**Chunk.cpp (Just an idea, this code doesn't work at all and isn't completed)**

```
void Chunk::Setup()
{
    for (uint8_t x = 0; x < 16; ++x)
    {
        for (uint8_t y = 0; y < 16; ++y)
        {
            for (uint8_t z = 0; z < 16; ++z)
            {
                blocks[x][y][z] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vao);
    glGenBuffers(1, &m_vbo);

    glBindVertexArray(m_vao);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(uint8_t) * 16 * 16 * 16, blocks, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void Chunk::Draw(Shader& p_shader)
{
    glBindVertexArray(m_vao);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

**voxel.glsl**

```
#shader vertex
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec3 v_pos;

void main()
{
    v_pos = position;
}

#shader geometry
#version 330 core

layout (points) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 24) out;

uniform vec3 u_position;
uniform mat4 u_vp;

const float textCount = 3.0f;

const vec3 cubeVertex[8] = vec3[8]
(
    /* Z+ (Front) */
    vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f),  // 0
    vec3(-0.5f, +0.5f, +0.5f),  // 1
    vec3(+0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f),  // 2
    vec3(+0.5f, +0.5f, +0.5f),  // 3

    /* Z- (Back) */
    vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),  // 4
    vec3(-0.5f, +0.5f, -0.5f),  // 5
    vec3(+0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),  // 6
    vec3(+0.5f, +0.5f, -0.5f)   // 7
);

const int  cubeIndices[24]  = int[24]
    (
        1,0,3,2,  // Z+ (Front)
        3,2,7,6,  // X+ (Right)
        7,6,5,4,  // Z- (Back)
        5,4,1,0,  // X- (Left)
        0,4,2,6,  // Y- (Bottom)
        5,1,7,3   // Y+ (Top)
    );

const vec2 textCoords[24] = vec2[24]
(
    vec2(1/textCount, 1),  vec2(1/textCount, 0), vec2(2/textCount, 1), vec2(2/textCount, 0), // Front
    vec2(1/textCount, 1),  vec2(1/textCount, 0), vec2(2/textCount, 1), vec2(2/textCount, 0), // Right
    vec2(1/textCount, 1),  vec2(1/textCount, 0), vec2(2/textCount, 1), vec2(2/textCount, 0), // Back
    vec2(1/textCount, 1),  vec2(1/textCount, 0), vec2(2/textCount, 1), vec2(2/textCount, 0), // Left
    vec2(2/textCount, 1),  vec2(2/textCount, 0), vec2(1, 1), vec2(1, 0), // Bottom
    vec2(0, 1),  vec2(0, 0), vec2(1/textCount, 1), vec2(1/textCount, 0) // Top
);

out vec2 textureCoord;
out float lighting;

void main() 
{
    mat4 model = mat4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  u_position.x, u_position.y, u_position.z, 1.0);
    mat4 mvp = u_vp * model;

    for (int i = 0; i < 24; ++i) 
    {
        gl_Position = mvp * (gl_in[0].gl_Position + vec4(cubeVertex[cubeIndices[i]], 0));
        textureCoord = textCoords[i];

        if (i >= 16 && i < 20)
            lighting = 0.2f;
        else if (i >= 20)
            lighting = 1.0f;
        else
            lighting = 0.6f;

        EmitVertex();
        if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0) EndPrimitive();
    }
}

#shader fragment
#version 330 core

uniform sampler2D tex;

out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 textureCoord;
in float lighting;

void main()
{
    // Final color
    FragColor = texture2D(tex, textureCoord) * lighting;
}
```

Comment: For drawing the same model many times, you typically want to use [instancing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing). With it, you will be able to render way, way more than 4096 cubes in a single draw call. In addition, you will avoid the performance hit that the geometry shader may be introducing.

Comment: @Acorn Hello Acorn, I read that instanced drawing works only if I don't use a geometry shader to generate my cubes. Is it a bad practice to use a geometry shader ? Should I switch to a simple obj and instanced drawing ?

Comment: For rendering many copies of models, indeed, switch to instanced drawing if you can. Geometry shaders were designed [with other (advanced) tasks in mind](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader), they are not meant to contain hardcoded models inside them.

Comment: @Acorn Mmmh... Okey, I'll read more about instanced drawing. In this case, will I have to send my data with uniforms or a VBO ?

Comment: For instancing, you will have to put your vertex data (e.g. the 6 positions in object space) in VBO(s). Then, you will need to send whatever data you need to vary for each instance (in your case, the translation) using, for instance, [instanced arrays](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Instanced_arrays).

Comment: @Acorn I dont get about which position (6 positions) you are talking about... The data that never change between blocks in the chunk is the position of the chunk, used to offset to blocks position

Comment: I was referring to the 8 vertexes a cube has (sorry, not 6 -- thinking about the faces :-). In other words, your model (a cube) consists of a set of 8 vertices (12 triangles). Typically, the vertices would sit at [-1, 1] in object space (with center at 0). Then, each cube will be translated into a different position; i.e. this is the data that you need to vary for each instance (and it is only a single vertex, i.e. a 3D position in world space). But the model (the 8 vertices/12 triangles) never changes so they can be shared among all instances.

Comment: @Acorn Okey, I get it ! Thanks for your time, I'll consider all of this to create my chunk !

Comment: If you want I implemented something similar to what you are doing, so perhaps looking at my code will help you:

https://github.com/Makogan/Nyx-Helios